# Resonance energy in benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, resonance, hydrocarbons

Quoting from my textbook:

> Although stabilized by resonance compared with other carbocations, its resonance energy is much less than that of the starting benzene ring.

Here is more context :

---

[image: textbook passage on the benzenonium ion, showing its canonical forms]

---

Isn't that good? Isn't it more stable if it had less energy? Shouldn't it stay that way?

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: Maybe try suggesting an alternative next time :)

Comment: It is potentially badly worded. Resonance energy is a negative quantity: it is how much *more* stable something is compared to the alternative (benzene is *more* stable than the theoretical cyclohexatriene with three double and three single bonds). But benzenonium ions have *less* resonance energy than benzene but more than other carbocations so have *higher* energy than benzene but *lower* energy than typical carbocations.

Comment: I would not even say that is poorly worded.